# How to format email body?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I'm opening an Outlook email from Excel.

I would like to format the body, e.g. using a certain font and making a few words bold.

Here is my VBA code for opening an email:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutMail
    .To = strRecipient
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .subject = strSubject
    .body = strBody
    .Display
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the [HTML mail format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175500.aspx) for that:

```
OutMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
OutMail.HTMLBody = "<b>Bold</b>, not bold"
```