# How to bold Outlook text from dynamic Excel cells in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to format the dynamic cells in the body to be bold.

I want the email body to look like that:

> Dear User,
>
> The following request is in I8.1 Check Resource Availability:
>
> **Test Project**
>
> The estimated effort below is called out in the request's ROM (in hours):  **10** and duration (in business days):  **2** 
>   Do you have a named resource I can put in for the effort called out? Please provide me with an update at the earliest
>
> Thank you and best regards,
>
> Team.

This code is working but I can't find a way to **bold** the desired values.

```vb
Sub Sendmail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value) <> "0" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Resources awaiting assignment"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value _
                & ", " _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                     "The following request is in I8.1 Check Resource Availability: " _
                     & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                     Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "The estimated effort below is called out in the request's ROM (in hours):  " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value _
                    & _
                    " and duration (in business days):  " & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Do you have a named resource I can put in for the effort called out? Please provide me with an update at the earliest" _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Thank you and best regards, " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Team."

                .Display
            End With

            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I checked some posts on formating body of an email in VBA (e.g. [How to format email body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867013/how-to-format-email-body), [formatting email body using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248365/formatting-email-body-using-vba) or
[Bolding Text with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877637/bolding-text-with-vba)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.HTMLBody` instead of `.Body`

Then you can use HTML - Change your `vbNewLine` to `<br>` and use `<b> text here </b>` to make things bold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @braX, I know how to make the standard text bold, but as I mentioned in the post I'm struggling with bolding the "dynamic" cells here...

Comment: by "dynamic" do you mean `Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value`? - you just do it like this - `"<b>" & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "</b>"` - the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

BraX finished their answer, which contained all the important points, before me.  Perhaps you need my longer answer.

`Body` is the text body for an email.  `BodyHtml` is the Html body.

For Html, whitespace is defined as any of carriage return, linefeed, tab, space and some other more obscure characters.  Any string of whitespace is the equivalent of a single space.  So:

```
", " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The following request is in I8.1"
```

is the same as: `", The following request is in I8.1"`

because the string of whitespace characters - space newline newline - becomes a single space.  You need to start a paragraph with <P>.  A linebreak is created with <BR>.

The easiest, if old fashioned, way of formatting some text as bold is by enclosing it in <B>xxx</B>.

You have some double spaces in your text.  If you want extra spaces, you need to use a non-break space which you can specify with &NBSP;

So try:

```
.BodyHtml =  "<P>Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & ", " _
             "<P>The following request is in I8.1 Check Resource Availability: " _
             "<P><B>" & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "</B>" _
             "<P>The estimated effort below is called out in the request's ROM (in hours): &NBSP;" & _
                 "<B>" & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & "</B> and duration (in business days): &NBSP;" & _
                 "<B>" & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value  & "</B>" _
             "<P>Do you have a named resource I can put in for the effort called out? " & _
                 "Please provide me with an update at the earliest" _
             "<P>Thank you and best regards, <BR>" _
             "<P>Team."
```

I have not tested this VBA specified Html.  I hope there are no mistakes but I am sure you can see what I am attempting if there are mistakes.

Comment: Thank you Tony! Besides you missed some `&` at the endings and `&NBSP;` in the text is just being displayed as it is - it's perfectly fine